# Clienside validation before server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback

My issues:

1) Postback always occurs

2) Is that the correct way to see if requiredFieldValidator is valid client side?

What I would like:

User clicks the visible click button.

This invokes isValid().

If page is valid then invoke server side function.

If page is invalid do alert.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ToolTip="Submit" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="blueNew buttonNew" 
                OnClientClick="isValid(); return false;" />

<div style="display: none;">
    <asp:Button ID="hiddenBtnSubmit" runat="server"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
 </div>

 <script>
function isValid() {
    if (Page_IsValid) {
        var button = document.getElementByID("<%=hiddenBtnSubmit.ClientID%>");
        button.click();
    } else {
        if (!reqFirstName.IsValid) {
            alert("First name is invalid");
        }
    }      
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you just have to add the validators like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
    ErrorMessage="The email is required"
    ToolTip="The email is required"
    Text="(*)"
    ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
    runat="server" />
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" DisplayMode="BulletList" ShowMessageBox="true" />
```

And the validation will be executed on the client whenever you try to submit your form, you do not need to manually execute the validation

The output will be something like:

[image]

### Edit 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var val = Page_ClientValidate('');
        if (!val) {
            for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                    $("#" + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).qtip();
                }
            }
        }

        return val;
    }
</script>

<asp:Button OnClientClick="return validate();" Text="Post" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I want to display the returning message in a customised way? What would be the best way to go about that?

Comment: You can use a `ValidationSummary` control to display all the error messages, I will update the post to add an example

Comment: Okay, validation summary just show plain text I want to show the error msg using qtip tooltips on the postback is this possible?

Comment: Val always returns null am I trying the above to quickly? or should that work?

Comment: I have set Page_ClientValidate('vdEnquiry'); but val returns null on page load.

Comment: val should return true or false, what I'm still testing is if the qtip tooltip is displayed, I have not used qtip before, but again the `val` variable is working. If it is not in your case, specify your `ValidationGroup` when calling the `Page_ClientValidate` function if you are not using valdiation groups just call it with an empty string