# client-side events for asp.net validators

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to do an ajax-style form validation (with green checkmarks showing when input is valid) for my asp.net form.

For two fields I use a custom validator and use jquery ajax to validate the values. For these validators, I piggy-back on the client-side validation in order to show a progressbar while the ajax call is waiting for a response and a green checkmark, if the result is ok.

For the other inputs I have requiredfiled and regex validators, and I would rather not turn them all in to custom validators. Is there a client-side event called on validation for non-custom validators?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I believe all ASP.NET validators offer client script validation unless it is explicitly disabled on the control via EnableClientScript="false".

Comment: Then what is the difference between a custom validator and a requiredfield validator if I still need to provide the logic myself? I was looking for an event, not implementing the functionality myself.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question.  Would this help based on your description? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443006/clienside-validation-before-server-side

Comment: Do you want to show a progress bar while requiredfield performs it's validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter the client side `evaluationfunction` property on the validators

Documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719700(VS.71).aspx

Tutorial : http://blogbaris.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/creating-custom-validator-control-in.html

Comment: I wasn't looking to go into inheritance and such. I can always just use custom validators. I was just wondering if regular validators have client-side events I can use.